# Fetching data from database and populating a dropdownlist from a List<object> in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I have model:

```
public partial class UserRole
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public virtual user Users { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Roles { get; set; }
}

public partial class user
{
    public user()
    {
        Roles = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public long id { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime reg_date { get; set; }
    public byte validated { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }

    //public IEnumerable<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public partial class Role
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Controller to load the view:

```
public ActionResult AssignRole(long id = 0)
    {
        user UserModel = new user();
        int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        IList<user> Users = new List<user>();
        var query = from Role in db.Roles
                    join UserRole in db.UserRoles on Role.ID equals UserRole.RoleID
                    join user in db.users on UserRole.UserID equals user.id
                    where UserRole.UserID == UserId
                    select new { RoleName  = Role.RoleName, email = user.email, UserId = user.id };



        var userss = query.ToList();
        foreach(var userList in userss)
        {
            Users.Add(new user()
                {
                    id = userList.UserId,
                    email = userList.email,
                    RoleName = userList.RoleName
                });
        }

        LoadRoles(Users);
        return View(Users);
    }

public void LoadRoles(IList<user> model)
    {

        var Roles = db.Roles.AsQueryable<Role>().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
        {

            Text = x.RoleName,
            Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) x.ID)
        }).ToList();

        var UserModel = new user()
        {
            Roles = Roles.ToList()
        };

    }
```

I am able to get other values from the LINQ in the first part of view but unable to populate the dropdownlist.

```
<fieldset>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.email)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoleName)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.id })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>

<div class="display-label">
    @Html.DisplayName("Add Role")
</div>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(modeIteml => item.RoleId, item.Roles)
    </div>
}

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Assign" />
</p>
```

How can I populate the dropdownlist? I have tried so much but still no luck.

Comment: i think problem is with LoadRoles method because you have passed IList<user> model but there is not model.Roles assignment in method.

Comment: Can you show your `@model` in cshtml file? Maybe there is something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find it clearer if you write it like this:

```
public ActionResult AssignRole(int id = 0)
{
    var user = (from u in db.users
               join r in db.UserRoles on r.UserId equals u.id into g
               where u.id == id
               select new user
               {
                   id = u.id,
                   email = u.email,
 // assign the properties like any normal select.
                   Roles = g.Select(x => new Role { RoleName = x.rolename ... })
               })
               .FirstOrDefault();

    return View(user); // Update your view to expect a single user
}
```

This way you've gotten everything you need in one quick trip to the database, and your model represents what you have (a single user with multiple roles).

If you want a separate list of roles you can assign, I recommend putting in a separate view model for that scenario.  i.e.

```
public class AssignRolesModel 
{
    public user User { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Role> AvailableRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Then change return View(user) to:

```
var viewModel = new AssignRolesModel
               {
                   User = user,
                   Roles = db.Roles
                             .Select(x => 
                                new SelectListItem()
                                {
                                    Text = x.RoleName,
                                    Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) x.ID)
                                })
                             .ToList()
               };

return View(viewModel);
```

Comment: yea, i am getting values here from LoadRoles but unable to pass them to the main object. Any suggestion?

Comment: @naeemmalik you have to loop over each user object in model list and have to set Roles property because your Roles property is inside user object.

Comment: @Sandeep is right.  I'll update my answer to be clearer about best practice now that i'm not on my phone.

Comment: @Steve I am getting error in the LINQ query. it says, "The name 'r' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.". I have tried swapping the expressions but seems like not working yet. Might be Its because of the argument on the left of the "equals" operator needs to be a reference to a table used before. As i have referenced only Users n Roles but I have UserID from UserRole table that is not referenced.. Don't know how to fix it in your query. Also, what to pass in the Role that you commented as "// assign the properties" Thanks

Comment: If you don't need the user roles they currently have then you can remove the join and the assignment to roles. Otherwise make the join to user roles instead

Comment: I want the Roles from the same query but in the join i am getting error i posted. UserId property is from UserRole model so how to reference it.

Comment: If you want the roles for the user, per my comment, join to userRoles instead of roles. I've updated my answer.  If that doesn't give you enough data, then join to userroles, then join to roles from userroles, just like any SQL query.

Comment: I've updated the query like this.. var users = (from u in db.users
               join ur in db.UserRoles on u.id equals ur.UserID
               join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleID equals r.ID into g
               where u.id == id
               select new
               {
                   id = u.id,
                   email = u.email,
                   RoleName = u.RoleName,
                   Roles = g.Select(x => new Role { RoleName = x.RoleName })
               })
               .FirstOrDefault();      I need Roles for selected user from Roles entity but can't get it.

Comment: That sounds right.  Except new { should be new userModel { (so you can pass it out to the view, or assign it to a parent viewModel, etc)

Comment: I put usermodel but LINQ getting error "The entity or complex type 'user' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Comment: Ah, then you'll need to use an anonymous type like you have done and assign it after :)

Comment: yea, my previous query was working fine, but i couldn't get the Roles for dropdownlist. I've set the property in UserModel for the Roles as  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }. When i try to pass values from Roles to UserModel it gives explicit conversion error. Kindly help me in resolving that error.